# Cognito Forms: 'Save & Resume' problem with IE

Tags: cognito-forms

Is anyone having problems accessing (resuming) a saved form in Internet Explorer?  I sometimes can resume but sometimes IE only shows the form title and does not populate the questions or previously saved user input.  It seems to work fine in other browsers.

Comment: What version of IE?

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We have had reports of an issue using Save and Resume in Internet Explorer. We have found a bug related to this and released an update to correct the issue last night. You should now see the Save and Resume function work correctly in Internet Explorer.